# Sygic gps range error correction

Tags: rotation, gps, coordinates, sygic

i'm using Sygic SDK in my form (.net WinForms) with Gmap.NET to display the map. I have implemented map rotation based on GPS coordinates from Sygic. To rotate the map I create 2-3 vectors from last coordinates, add them and get the angle. The problem arise when u stand on one place, the coordinates are not the same due to GPS range error so the map starts randomly rotating.

I could have fixed that if i had that error value, but i only found HDoP (horizontal dilution of precision) in Sygic documentation and its only the scalar to multiply error. So if coordinates are in error range i don't rotate the map.

Is there any trick to computer error value? Is there different implementation?

Sygic also provides speed within coordinates struct. Should i try to use Speed instead? So do not rotate the map if speed is 0. Don't know if that would be accurate.

Sygic coordinates doc:http://developers.sygic.com/reference/cs/html/class_application_a_p_i_1_1_s_gps_position.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "map rotation based on GPS coordinates from Sygic"

No, ist should not be based on the coordinates, but better by the "course" attribute.

> "So if coordinates are in error range i don't rotate the map."

No, better is, you don't rotate the map if the device is standing still. Use the speed attribute for that case.

> Sygic also provides speed within coordinates struct. Should i try to
>   use Speed instead? So do not rotate the map if speed is 0. Don't know
>   if that would be accurate.

Yes! but you should use a threshold above 0: 
So if speed < speedthreshold do not rotate.

Comment: hmm i didnt notice Course attribute, it could have saved my time with math. I will definitely reimplement it. I will try speed with threshhold. It looks promising.